# Remove duplicate records in history file of KSH

Tags: shell, ksh

how can I set in ksh's .kshrc that duplicate records in history file will be deleted after every command?

Thanks

Comment: This is underspecified. Do you want to keep the first or the last of duplicate entries?

Comment: The last. For example, when in history is: A B C D and I run command C, in history should be A B D C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ksh93` has never supported an option to rewrite history.

Some shells only write their history file on exit, or on request.  `ksh93` writes it after every command, which would generate lots of synchronous I/O.

In some environments (e.g., NFS) this could affect the interactive experience, causing the shell to wait after each command.

Comment: Confirmed. `zsh` has several options regarding history dupes though and has a `ksh` compatibility mode, but since I don't use `zsh` myself I can't comment on how compatible that really is.

Comment: Ok. I'll write my script then. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a ksh buff, so can't really tell if there's a shell option to ignore duplicates in history. Anyway, you can always trim duplicates with a little perl script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my $history = ".history";
open (HIST, '<', $history) or die "cannot read $history: $!";
my @oldhist = <HIST>;
close HIST;

my @newhist = ();
my %seen = ();
while (my $cmd = pop @oldhist) {
    next if defined $seen{$cmd};
    ++$seen{$cmd};
    unshift @newhist, $cmd;
}

open (HIST, '>', $history) or die "cannot write $history: $!";
print HIST @newhist;
close HIST;
```

This turns

```
A
B
C
D
C
```

into

```
A
B
D
C
```